# python database result will not work on if statement

Tags: python

I am running a python script which connects to a database retrieves one column, 6 rows long with integers of 0 or 1  or 2. These are placed in variables and I wanted to run an IF statement for specific conditions, but the IF statement will not work.

My data coming in from the database when printed out looks like this.

```
[(0,), (0,), (0,), (0,), (0,), (0,)]
```

My python result script below

```
def readDbHeating():

   cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()
   result = []
   try:
       cursor.execute("SELECT control FROM house_DB")
       for reading in cursor.fetchall():
           result.append(reading)
   except () as e:
       print(e)
   return (result)

while 1:
   result = readDbHeating()
   print result

   waterState = result[0]
   denState = result[3]
   niamhState = result[4]
   downWCstate = result[5]
```

below IF statement is not working when waterState is equal to 0

```
   if(waterState == 0):
      print("here")
      flag = 0
      print("Water state = %s ") % waterState
```

I've tried putting the 0 as "0" and I have tried converting the incoming result for waterState to an integer but I get the error this is a tuple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`waterState` is never `0`: it's always a tuple (a set of values in round brackets).

When you get your data as `[(0,), (0,), (0,), (0,), (0,), (0,)]` and store that in `results`, you have a list of 6 tuples.

`waterstate = results[0]` puts the value `(0,)` into the variable `waterstate`; this is a tuple, and will never be a single integer.

If you want to take just the first value from the tuple, you need to go one level deeper: `waterstate = results[0][0]`.

This selects the first value of the tuple in the first place in the list:

`[(0,), (0,), (0,), (0,), (0,), (0,)]` --> `(0,)` --> `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the data comes in as "0," not "0" have you seen if that works?

Comment: Tried if(waterState == "0,") this did not work, if I print out waterState I get (0,)

Comment: what variable type does it come in as? If i run it with the result as ```result = ["(0,)", "(0,)", "(0,)", "(0,)", "(0,)", "(0,)"] ```and the if statment as  ```if(waterState == "(0,)": ``` it works so its probably due to the type of data coming in

Comment: Just seen above!